# Which code should I use to show related posts/docs on a docpad index-website?

Tags: plugins, docpad

Unfortunately I am no scripting-guru. So this might be obvious for the most of you.

I installed the `docpad-plugin-related` plugin and it works on individual posts/docs when I include the following code ([see instructions](https://github.com/docpad/docpad-plugin-related#usage))

Now, I would like to show posts/docs sorted by tag on my index-website. For example posts/docs tagged with `webdesign` should show up as a list. How do I have to change the following code for this purpose?

```
<ul>
<% for document in @document.relatedDocuments: %>
   <li><a href="<%= document.url %>"><%= document.title %></a></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Is there a solution or does the plugin only work on individual posts/docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `docpad-plugin-related` plugin is all about getting the related documents on an individual document which is not what you want.  You don't need a plugin to do what you want.

Assuming your documents all have a `tags` property, you can get a list of documents that match a specific tag (e.g. `webdesign`) with code on your index page like this:

```
<ul>
<% for doc in @getCollection('documents').findAll({tags: '$in': `webdesign`}).toJSON(): %>
    <li><a href="<%= doc.url %>"><%= doc.title %></a></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

If you want tag specific indexes for all of your tags, you probably want to look at `docpad-plugin-tagging` ([link](https://github.com/rantecki/docpad-plugin-tagging)).

Comment: Worked like a charm, Erv. Slowly I get how this @getCollection-Loop-Thang works. Do you know a place where I can look up the syntax and possibilities for the filter? This works like a filter right? => (`findAll({tags: '$in': `webdesign`})`)

Comment: It's a library called Query Engine (developed by the same person who created DocPad).  Documentation here: https://github.com/bevry/query-engine/wiki/Using